# VSCode でシリアルターミナルがドロップダウンメニューに表示されなくなってしまった

Tags: spresense, vscode

Visual Studio Codeでシリアルターミナルが表示されなくなりました。(下記画像)
TeraTermでは、NuttShellが起動してアプリの実行が出来るので、ポートドライバの問題では無いようです。
「4.5.1. シリアルポートの設定」を何度も試しても復旧しません。
このような状況からVisual Studio Codeでシリアルターミナルを動作させる方法をご存じの方はお教えください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: まず `Spresense SDK` でインストールされた `bash` で `screen` コマンドを使ったシリアルポート接続ができるか確認を してみてください。

Comment: それが 問題なければあとは `Visual Studio Code` の `setting.json` で `terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows` 定義で起動するアプリを指定すればいいでしょう。 `Spresense SDK`  が どのような設定で bash の screen を自動実行しているかその仕組みは、まだ調べてませんが  `bash_profile` 等の設定かな？？。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。質問に書き忘れましたが、こちらはWindows環境です。その為、msys2デフォルトインストールではscreenコマンドがインストールされていません。

Comment: https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_msys2_%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%ABpath%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9Awindows%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF の 部分はちゃんとやってますよね？？

Comment: また https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_msys2_%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%ABpath%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9Awindows%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF も

Comment: はい。 [https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_msys2_%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%ABpath%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9Awindows%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF]  を行って、msys64のパスを選択しています。

Answer (score 0):

[3. アプリケーションプロジェクトの作成](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)

に書いてあるように新しくプロジェクト設定を行うか

`[F1]` キーを押して `spresense` を入力
その一覧の中にある `シリアルターミナルを開く` を選んでみてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。[シリアルターミナルを開く]を選択すると一瞬シリアルターミナルが表示されてウインドウの右下に[ターミナルの処理が終了しました(終了コード:1)]が表示されます。

Comment: アプリケーションプロジェクトを作成していないとシリアルターミナルが使えないようです。特に「3.2. シェル設定の有効化」が重要なようです。ここまで実施しないとシリアルターミナルが使えないようです。

Answer (score 0):

私も一度表示されなくなったことがありました。
その時は、VSCodeとは別にTera TermでSpresenseのポートを使用していたことが原因でした。

一つのポートを同時に開くことはできないと思いますので、他にSpresenseのポートを使用しているものが無いかを確認してみるといいかもしれません。確認できない場合は再起動すれば恐らく解消するのではないかと思います。

ご参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。VSCodeとTeraTerm等のターミナルソフトを同時に使用しておりません。